# Should I create model files when only visualizing data in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I started working on first small rails project which will in fact get data from database and visualize in jquery datatable. There will be no updates at all. The question is, should I create models for this data and access it through activerecord or it is ok to access it directly through SQL commands in controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still make models to keep the controller clean.

Rails pattern is that all data access should be done through the models. You don't necessarily have to have any update/insert logic or even inherit from ActiveRecord, but that's where readers of your code would expect to find the data access.

Furthermore, you will need to pass some sort of object to your views, and it makes the most sense to use a model rather than a throw away temp object. This way you can cleanly change the model and only have one place to update.

For example, say you later need to add a `full_name` attribute to your report. If you had straight SQL in the controller and you were just passing the query results to the view, you'd have a harder time concatinating `first_name` and `last_name`. But with a model, you can just add

```
def full_name
    "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
end
```

in one place, and all the controller actions that show that report now have a `full_name` property.

If you plan to do testing, having a model class makes that a heck of a lot easier as well. You can test the model without having to get the controller involved.

Comment: Ok I have table with name table1_data , how the a) model class name b) model filename - should look like. Thanks.